# WPF - determine which control is visible in Canvas in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, window, visibility, scrollviewer

I have something like this in xaml page:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PreviewvideosScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="1366" Height="480" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In code I added lots of controls to canvas and many of them are out of window. How can I determine which of these controls are visible (user see in screen) and which not?

I tried sample code like this:

```
private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        if (!element.Parent.Equals(VideoCanvas))
            return true;
        //// position of your visual inside the scrollviewer    
        GeneralTransform childTransform = element.TransformToAncestor(VideoCanvas);
        Rect rectangle = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), element.RenderSize));

        ////Check if the elements Rect intersects with that of the scrollviewer's
        Rect result = Rect.Intersect(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), VideoCanvas.RenderSize), rectangle);
        ////if result is Empty then the element is not in view
        return result != Rect.Empty;
    }
```

or this:

```
private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
    {
        if (!element.IsVisible)
            return false;

        var bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
        var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
        return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
    }
```

But both aren't working. Where could be problem? With canvas in scrollviewer? Or something else? Thanks

Comment: What are your reasons for using a Canvas? Would a different layout container suit your needs? Have you checked that the bounds of the elements are correct, as incorrectly reported or used sizing / positioning values could cause your intersection checks to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's say you have control in Canvas.

You want to obtain its cordinates relative to ScrollViewer and then you want to check if cordinates are between 0 and ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth & ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight.

How do you convert Canvas cordinates to ScrollViewer cordinates?

First, let's not take scrolling into account and assume that Canvas is smaller than ScrollViewer and its HorizontalAlignment is set to Left and VerticalAlignment to Top.

to obtain Controls cordinates relative to ScrollViewer, it's simple matter of using this:

```
var x = Canvas.GetLeft(YourControl);

var y = Canvas.GetTop(YourControl);
```

Now assume that we also have scrolling applied.

```
var x = Canvas.GetLeft(YourControl) - ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;

var y = Canvas.GetTop(YourControl) - ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

if(x >= 0 && x <= ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth && y <= ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight)
  return true; // YAY
```

Makes sense, no?

Comment: And I was thinking about how hard it would be. With that offset and viewport it's very easy and clear. Thanks

Comment: hehe yeah, your case is easy, but I did something similiar in winRT. There I had zooming of Control(RenderTransform) and I also had zooming on ScrollViewer. Plus the rotation on Control. And Canvas was centered on ScrollViewer, so it required extra calculations. It soon became super mess :P.